# Using a WebBrowser, can you access to all downloaded/ing files?

Tags: c#, browser

Let's say that I navigate to google. It will download several files, including artworks, js scripts, etc. Can I access it from a member of WebBrowser, and if not, is there a special methodology to follow, in .Net? I already know HtmlAgilityPack, but it is for local file only. Websites behavior relies on a very strict structure from live, online documents and scripts, so I need something that works with online websites.

Comment: Simply look up `c# WebClient`.

Comment: Isn't this a HttpWebRequest helper? It can't manage script reading and media handling.

Comment: But even HTMLAgilityPack seems to be limited to local file.

Answer (score 0):

The WebBrowser of C# is an old browser and because of this you can't do any complex things like downloading from it. But there is a class in c# called WebClient by which you can download and upload what you want...

Comment: I'm able to fully use the nice and recent website I want to explore with WebBrowser, which I know is something like IE8 or IE9.

Comment: WebClient is an helper for HttpWebRequest, which is itself an helper to avoid to manually make get/post socket communications. Thanks.